# Регистрация с подтверждением по почте django

Tags: python, django

Сделал сброс пароля с помощью email c стандартной формой PasswordResetForm. Можно как то сделать регистрацию с подтверждением по почте с помощью UserCreationForm?

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('personalArea/', views.personalArea, name='personalArea'),

    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
]
```

#### views.py

```
def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.POST:
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                my_password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')

                user = authenticate(username=username, password=my_password1)
                if user and user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/personalArea/')
                else:
                    form.add_error(None, 'Unknown or disabled account')
                    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})

            else:
                return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': RegistrationForm()})
    else:
        return redirect('/personalArea/')
```

#### forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, label='Логин', min_length=2)
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, label='Пароль', min_length=8)
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, label='Повторите пароль', min_length=8)
    firstname = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=25,label='Номер телефона', min_length=10)

    error_messages = {
        'password_mismatch': ("Пароли не совпадают."),
        'error': ("Форма не валидна."),
        'username_exists': _("Пользователь с таким именем уже существует."),
    }

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'firstname',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
       )

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
            # if the user exists, then let's raise an error message
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['username_exists'],  # my error message
                code='username_exists',  # set the error message key
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username  # if user does not exist so we can continue the registration process

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['firstname']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

#### register.html

```
{% extends  'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
{% if not user.is_authenticated %}
<div class="container">
<h1 class="text-center">Регистрация</h1>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">
        <form method="post" action="{% url 'register' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
            <p>
              {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    <p class="register-error">{{ error }}</p>
              {% endfor %}
              {{ field }}
              {% if field.help_text %}
              <span class="help-text-register">{{ field.help_text }}</span>
              {% endif %}

            </p>
            {% endfor %}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Зарегистрироваться</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
<h1 class="text-center">Вы уже зарегистрированы!</h1>
<h5 class="text-center">Чтобы зарегистрировать новый аккаунт, выйдете из текущего.</h5>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: а что именно хотите? чтобы приходила ссылка при переходе по которой активировался акаунт или какой-то код при вводе в другую форму чтобы активировался?

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin
Да как легче так и сделать, главное чтоб подтверждение по почте было, можно через код, либо через ссылку при переходе которой происходит активация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

пример с отправкой кода на почту для активации.

1 Добавить к модели пользователя code

2 Установить флаг пользователя is_active в False

```
def generate_code():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(10000,99999))

def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.POST:
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                my_password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                code = generate_code()
                message = code
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=my_password1)
                send_mail('код подтверждения', message,
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                ['test@mail.ru'], 
                fail_silently=False)  
                if user and user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/personalArea/')
                else: #тут добавить редирект на страницу с формой для ввода кода.
                    form.add_error(None, 'Unknown or disabled account')
                    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})

            else:
                return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': 
            RegistrationForm()})
    else:
        return redirect('/personalArea/')

#написать обработчик 2 формы 
def endreg(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NameForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("key")
            user = User.objects.get(code=code_use)
            user.is_active = True
            user.save()
     else:
         form = NameForm1()
```

Примерно как-то так. Скорее всего endreg функцию предется подправить, но смысл должен быть понятен

Comment: Спасибо, попробую отпишусь, я новичек в django, как к стандартной модели User
добавить любое другое поле, это создается заново полностью модель User?

Comment: @ArtemWelly с помощью `OneToOneField`  `class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)`

Comment: @ArtemWelly можно как вариант хранить код в сессии и тогда наверное не придется добавлять поле в модель `request.session["code"] = code request.session["username"] = username` в функции `register`
и получать его во второй `code_session = request.session.get("code", " ")` 
`user_session = request.session.get("username", " ")` и потом искать пользователя так `User.objects.get(username=user_session)`

Comment: Как сделать уникальный код, чтобы не повторялся в базе данных, либо удалялся , если чел не активировал его после определенного времени допустим 1-2 дня, можно ли как то сделать ссылку не общую для активации а ссылка + номер сгенерированный или как сделать лучше?

Answer (score 0):

В общем сделал работает, есть проблема в том, что код который отсылается сохраняется в базе, его нужно потом как то удалять через время , когда он не активен, иначе будут наложения если вдруг другому пользователю срандомится такой же код, либо нужно как то сделать ссылку отличную от стандартной.Может есть идеи как сделать лучше?

#### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('personalArea/', views.personalArea, name='personalArea'),
    path('register/', views.register, name="register"),
    path('activation_code_form/', views.endreg, name="endreg"),
    path('',views.activation, name='activation'),
]
```

#### views.py

```
def generate_code():
    random.seed()
    return str(random.randint(10000,99999))

def register(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.POST:
            form = RegistrationForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                my_password1 = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
                u_f = User.objects.get(username=username, email=email, is_active=False)
                code = generate_code()
                if Profile.objects.filter(code=code):
                    # for p in Profile.objects.filter(code=code):
                    #     p.delete()
                    code = generate_code()

                message = code
                user = authenticate(username=username, password=my_password1)
                now = datetime.datetime.now()

                Profile.objects.create(user=u_f, code=code, date=now)

                send_mail('код подтверждения', message,
                settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
                [email],
                fail_silently=False)
                if user and user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/personalArea/')
                else: #тут добавить редирект на страницу с формой для ввода кода.
                    form.add_error(None, 'Аккаунт не активирован')
                    return redirect('/activation_code_form/')
                    # return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})

            else:
                return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':
            RegistrationForm()})
    else:
        return redirect('/personalArea/')

def endreg(request):
    if  request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('/personalArea/')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = MyActivationCodeForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                code_use = form.cleaned_data.get("code")
                if Profile.objects.filter(code=code_use):
                    profile = Profile.objects.get(code=code_use)
                else:
                    form.add_error(None, "Код подтверждения не совпадает.")
                    return render(request, 'registration/activation_code_form.html', {'form': form})
                if profile.user.is_active == False:
                    profile.user.is_active = True
                    profile.user.save()
                    # user = authenticate(username=profile.user.username, password=profile.user.password)
                    login(request, profile.user)
                    profile.delete()
                    return redirect('/personalArea/')
                else:
                    form.add_error(None, '1Unknown or disabled account')
                    return render(request, 'registration/activation_code_form.html', {'form': form})
            else:
                return render(request, 'registration/activation_code_form.html', {'form': form})
        else:
            form = MyActivationCodeForm()
            return render(request, 'registration/activation_code_form.html', {'form': form})
```

#### models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='profile', default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True, null=True, default=None)
    date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

#### forms.py

```
class MyActivationCodeForm(forms.Form):
    error_css_class = 'has-error'
    error_messages = {'password_incorrect':
                          ("Старый пароль не верный. Попробуйте еще раз."),
                      'password_mismatch':
                          ("Пароли не совпадают."),
                      'cod-no':
                          ("Код не совпадает."),}


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyActivationCodeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    code = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=50, label='Код подтвержения', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),  error_messages={'required': 'Введите код!','max_length': 'Максимальное количество символов 50'})



    def save(self, commit=True):
        profile = super(MyActivationCodeForm, self).save(commit=False)
        profile.code = self.cleaned_data['code']

        if commit:
            profile.save()
        return profile

class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Email')
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=15, label='Логин',  min_length=2)
    password1 = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, label='Пароль', min_length=8)
    password2 = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=30, label='Повторите пароль')
    firstname = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=25, label='Номер телефона', )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'firstname',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
       )

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get("username")
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(username=username)
            # if the user exists, then let's raise an error message
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                self.error_messages['username_exists'],  # my error message
                code='username_exists',  # set the error message key
            )
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username  # if user does not exist so we can continue the registration process

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['firstname']
        user.password1 = self.cleaned_data['password1']
        user.password2 = self.cleaned_data['password2']
        user.is_active = False

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

Comment: Я в комментариях написал как модно сделать через сессии, тогда код не будет хранится в бд. А вообще лучше в отдельный вопрос оформите

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin
А как можно сделать , кнопку по нажатию на которой , будет снова выслан код ?

Comment: можно . Повесить обработчик на кнопку повторного отправления кода